# scalable iteration with dicts

Tags: python, numpy

Given this code:

```
K = list(np.arange(0, 5, 1))
steps = list(np.arange(1, 10, 2))
alpha = list(np.arange(0.0001, 0.0010, 0.0001))
beta = list(np.arange(0.0001, 0.0010, 0.0001))

param_grid = {'k': k,
              'steps': steps,
              'alpha': alpha,
              'beta': beta}
```

The final param_grid is a dict with 4 items, which 4 lists that contain general numbers between integers and floats. The goal is iterate with all the possibilites, which means the total loops must be equal multiply all length lists.

It's easy crafting many "for" loops, therefore is tried to get a less verbose solution.

Comment: Why do you create a numpy array and then convert it to a list? This is very inefficient. You should use `range()` or use `np.array` directly.

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function in the standard library creates a cartesian product of iterables. It takes any number of iterables as arguments and returns an iterator over tuples in the Cartesian product.

So to loop over all possible combinations, you can use:

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

for c in product(*param_grid.values()):
    # do something with c
    # the first value of c in your case will be (0, 1, 0.0001, 0.0001)
```

You can also unpack each tuple to get access to individual components of the 4-tuple, for example:

```
for k, s, a, b in product(*param_grid.values()):
    # do something with any of those four variables
```